# Алгоритм нахождения уникальных слов в тексте

Tags: c++builder, алгоритм

Как в C++ Builder, при создании текстового редактора, написать функцию, которая ищет в тексте слова, которые встречаются только по одному разу?
Код, пожалуйста...

Comment: сам попробуй написать, полезно и интересно, можем только алгоритм и инструменты подсказать =)

Comment: времени нету..до завтра надо, так бы написалА))

ну подскажи..

Comment: спасибо, но я сама на первом курсе,и то, что тут написано пока мало о чем мне говорит..

Answer (score 1):

Помнится мы такую задачу решали на 1м курсе, посему предложу свое решение.

Пункт 1й как у [@gecube](/users/907/gecube). Второй выбрасываете, а вот в третьем пункте я бы заменил список на бинарное дерево. В сим бинарном дереве элементы добавляются как обычно, за исключением случая совпадения слов, для чего каждый элемент дерева снабжается некоторым полем, считающим количество вхождений данного слова (соответственно новый элемент не добавляется).

Затем очень легко работать с этим деревом. И, соответственно, расширять ваше задание.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вытаскиваете из текста очередное слово
2. Ищете его в тексте. Посмотрите стандартные ф-ции для работы со строками. Также полезно почитать про ф-ции для работы с компонентом для ввода текста. Среди них тоже может оказаться удобная ф-ция поиска и/или замены.
3. Если вхождения есть и их более одного - переход к п.1, иначе сначала добавляем слово в список слов, встречающихся однократно.

Вариант 2:
Убираете все лишнее (знаки препинания, множественные пробелы и пр.). Далее сортируете слова по алфавиту или любым удобным Вам способом. При этом не забудьте о разделителе между словами. Затем достаточно один раз пройтись по отсортированному массиву и сравнить последовательно идущие элементы. Понятно, что одинаковые слова при сортировке попадут рядом.